# Incomplete .js file is loaded in the browser

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, apache, flask

I have my `.js` file placed in the static folder. When I run my application in the local `flask` server, I don't get any `js` error in the console, And the application works fine.

But now my application is in the Apache server. The directory structure is same as in the local. But I am getting a `js` error in the console.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

I see in the browser the `js` file is not complete.

[image]

There is more code in my `js` file below the error, but it somehow gets stuck. If I remove few empty lines from above the code, the error slips down to next line.

Any suggestions what could be the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Clearing the cache might help ..?

Comment: @Teemu I cleared the cache, but it didn't work. It still gives me error.